# Handling different vector lengths caused by na.omit in sapply?

Tags: r, apply, na

I have a data.frame with several columns some of which contain NAs. I want to run the following function suggested by Farnsworth over every single column:

```
hpfilter = function(x,lambda=1600){
   eye <- diag(length(x))
   result <- solve(eye+lambda*crossprod(diff(eye,lag=1,d=2)),x)
   return(result)
 }
```

I do so by:

```
test <- as.data.frame(sapply(vectorOfColumnNames,function(X) hpfilter(mydf[,X])))
```

which works fine as long as none of the columns contain NAs. If I add an `na.omit` to the function it continues to work well with the same amount of NAs.

But how can I handle every column truly on its own and end up with a data.frame at the end (that contains NAs where the input had NAs) ?

EDIT: I wonder whether there is a general solution to the problem of ending up with vectors of different length when running a function over apply. Maybe something similar to what is possible with `data.table` indexing.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to remove all rows that contain `NA`?

Comment: thanks for trying to help Andrie, I know it might not be my best question. Paul figured it out exactly though.

Answer (score 4):

It is not completely clear to me what you want, but I'll give it a try.

Let's create some example data. Note that I use a `matrix` and not a `data.frame`. Explicitely iterating over the columnnames is now not needed, greatly simplifying the code.

```
m = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
apply(m, 2, hpfilter)
```

And introduce some `NA` values:

```
m[sample(1:10, 2), sample(1:10, 2)] <- NA
apply(m, 2, hpfilter)
```

A tweak to the `hpfilter` function yields the result, I believe, you are looking for:

```
hpfilter = function(x,lambda=1600, na.omit = TRUE) {
   if(na.omit) {
      na_values = is.na(x)
      if(any(na_values)) x = x[-which(na_values)]
   }
   eye <- diag(length(x))
   result <- solve(eye+lambda*crossprod(diff(eye,lag=1,d=2)),x)
   for(idx in which(na_values)) result = append(result, NA, idx - 1) # reinsert NA values
   return(result)
 }
```

Essentially, `NA`'s are torn out of the dataset. The high pass filter is then based on the values surrounding the `NA`, e.g. the next or previous hour. Later the `NA`'s are reintroduced. You need to think carefully if this is the way you want to deal with `NA`'s. If there are a large number of consecutive `NA`'s, you start apply your high pass filter to pieces of the timeseries which are far apart.

The output:

```
> m
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
 [1,] 0.3492249 0.13243768         NA 0.302102537 0.4229100 0.5922950
 [2,] 0.2933371 0.20001802 0.03145775 0.429109073 0.9597172 0.9490127
 [3,] 0.7040072 0.49672438 0.22093906 0.323518480 0.4842678 0.4081306
 [4,] 0.9072993 0.86930200 0.52859786 0.122859661 0.1841663 0.5389729
 [5,] 0.3236061 0.38602856 0.46249498 0.866068888 0.6981199 0.9766099
 [6,] 0.4878379 0.31511419         NA 0.807535084 0.6563737 0.0419552
 [7,] 0.3244131 0.34287848 0.31360175 0.821228400 0.5989790 0.6631735
 [8,] 0.3758025 0.39728965 0.64960319 0.283663049 0.9054992 0.8160815
 [9,] 0.4485784 0.06440579 0.67518605 0.815575767 0.1479089 0.6391120
[10,] 0.9061172 0.16812244 0.86293095 0.005075972 0.6736308 0.7574890
             [,7]       [,8]      [,9]       [,10]
 [1,]          NA 0.02125704 0.7029417 0.490146887
 [2,] 0.353827474 0.40482437 0.2102700 0.351850122
 [3,] 0.778491744 0.32676623 0.6709055 0.953126856
 [4,] 0.825446342 0.24411303 0.4939415 0.026877439
 [5,] 0.264156057 0.30620799 0.0474103 0.505411467
 [6,]          NA 0.63995093 0.6155766 0.736349958
 [7,] 0.048948805 0.96751061 0.9697167 0.005304793
 [8,] 0.733419331 0.85554984 0.7438209 0.581133546
 [9,] 0.823691194 0.74550281 0.0635690 0.903188495
[10,] 0.009001798 0.74201923 0.3516963 0.904093070
> apply(m, 2, hpfilter)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
 [1,] 0.4337716 0.4101083        NA 0.4239194 0.5762643 0.6178718        NA
 [2,] 0.4512989 0.3950404 0.1219334 0.4367185 0.5756097 0.6219962 0.5909609
 [3,] 0.4687735 0.3797990 0.2209373 0.4494414 0.5748593 0.6261047 0.5593590
 [4,] 0.4860436 0.3640885 0.3198847 0.4620073 0.5741572 0.6303856 0.5276089
 [5,] 0.5031048 0.3476868 0.4187190 0.4742566 0.5735911 0.6348910 0.4956993
 [6,] 0.5202157 0.3306871        NA 0.4858177 0.5730049 0.6396161        NA
 [7,] 0.5375230 0.3132068 0.5175141 0.4965640 0.5723201 0.6447694 0.4638051
 [8,] 0.5551529 0.2953536 0.6163712 0.5065697 0.5715107 0.6501860 0.4319566
 [9,] 0.5730986 0.2772537 0.7152643 0.5161124 0.5705671 0.6557125 0.3999246
[10,] 0.5912411 0.2590969 0.8141878 0.5253298 0.5696884 0.6612990 0.3676684
           [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
 [1,] 0.1423571 0.5362741 0.3871990
 [2,] 0.2276829 0.5253623 0.4217619
 [3,] 0.3129329 0.5145546 0.4563892
 [4,] 0.3981423 0.5037583 0.4911015
 [5,] 0.4833547 0.4929783 0.5262298
 [6,] 0.5685175 0.4822135 0.5618152
 [7,] 0.6534674 0.4711843 0.5978857
 [8,] 0.7380857 0.4596942 0.6345782
 [9,] 0.8224501 0.4478587 0.6716594
[10,] 0.9067115 0.4359704 0.7088627
```

Comment: +1, thx for your very good guessing and your elaborate answer. You are totally right introducing `na.omit` to the filter causes trouble with the time series if the NAs are in the middle of the series. Nevertheless the suggested approach helps in my case, because I have a data.frame of GDPs which are available at different length for different countries and I do not want to call the hpfilter separately for each column.